# Giving a device a hostname

Tags: router, ip

When I connect a device to my router, or if I use a tool like Advanced IP Scanner to look for devices on my network, the found devices are typically listed with and IP and a hostname. On Windows the hostname can be found by typing `hostname` in cmd.

Some devices, like an embedded device I'm working on, are listed as "unknown" or the IP is simply repeated in the Name column.

My question is, how are these names found by the router/Advanced IP Scanner? What exactly do I need to implement on my device to give it a hostname? I already have NetBIOS working, but this does not seem to be related to the hostname.

Comment: The network stack itself, up through OSI layer 4 that is on-topic here, does not use names, only addresses, e.g. MAC addresses, IP addresses, UDP/TCP ports, etc. A device name is an application-layer construct, which, unfortunately, is off-topic here. You could try to ask about host/server configuration topics, including names, on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways a host can decide the hostname of a given IP address.  For the circumstance you're describing, where some of your devices are not using your available mechanisms to register their own names, you can

- enter them in your reverse DNS zone if you have one, or failing that
- enter them in your `/etc/hosts` or equivalent on your scanning host.

Comment: Preferably I would like my device to register its hostname. The device is using the lwIP embedded TCP/IP stack. Any idea which features I should try to enable for it to work? Is it related to DNS? Thanks!

Comment: Adding the IP in my hosts file like you suggested worked, but as i mentioned, I would prefer for the name to be registered automatically.

Comment: You'll have to add a lot more information about the devices which you're dealing with, and what you're wanting them to register against.  If you're programming them yourself, you might find better luck with network programmers at Stack  Overflow, as this kind of thing is somewhat off-brief for network engineering.  You might ask about using `NETBIOS_LWIP_NAME`; I didn't find anything for DDNS or DHCP hostnames.